# Android passing objects between activities

Tags: android

Say if I have a locationManager(LM) object in activity A, which is my main menu. All the sub-activities need to use LM. In a good design, should I pass LM object to sub-activities? How? Please suggest some good coding pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an Application object, that is what [API proposes for those cases](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), when you have multiple Activities with common state.

Comment: Foursquare is a good example of using the Application object: http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/