# How to pass socket, inputstream, outputstream objects between activities

Tags: android

How to pass socket, inputstream, outputstream objects between activities

Comment: AFAIK, Object passed between activity through Bundle must be serializable 
and socket, inputstream, outputstream aren't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the application object, I think you can accomplish what you're looking for. See examples and discussion here:

[Android passing objects between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696684/android-passing-objects-between-activities)

Comment: I've tested this and a new application is created for the new activity.  I've also tested and confirmed Francesco's comment.  It appears that activities can't share non-serializable data and using an application object is only useful for saving data when the activity is destroyed and the same one is recreated (e.g. when orientation changes).

Comment: Sounds like nonsens. I use application for several setups that get only started once. However you can just usa a static class with static fields to share your data.

Comment: You can't pass streams through intents. Streams are initialized from data and store information such as position and length. When sockets are involved, you have an established connection with a remote server. You can't pass that across Activities, or especially different services.