# How to send TCP Sockets from one Activity to another in android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-activity

Assume that i have created a client TCP Socket in Activity A. I want to send that Socket to Activity B. Now in Activity B, based on some conditions i will close that socket. The problem is intent.putExtra() doesnot support sending sockets. So how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass socket, inputstream, outputstream objects between activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137223/how-to-pass-socket-inputstream-outputstream-objects-between-activities)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think that there are multiple activities that "own" a socket, then none of them should "own" the socket. Something else, like a `Service`, should be in charge of managing the socket. In this case, Activity A could start a `Service` to do the socket work, and Activity B can stop the service when the socket is no longer needed.

Otherwise, if those activities are that tightly coupled, they should not be separate activities. Activities are designed to be loosely coupled, akin to Web pages in a Web app.

Comment: ya true. But you need some reference to close that socket. right?so what is that reference?

Comment: @vij: "But you need some reference to close that socket. right?" -- not if it is managed by a service. The "reference", from the standpoint of your activities, is the service's name, or whatever you are using to construct the `Intent` to identify the service for your `startService()` and `stopService()` calls. The service itself holds your socket and manages the threads for communications on that socket (e.g., forks a thread to listen on that socket for incoming messages).

Comment: The Service itself. You make calls to the SErvice which then takes the appropriate action. The SErvice 'manages' the TCP connection

Comment: hey assume that i have created a socket like :Socket clientSocket = new Socket();clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 16789), 3000); in Activity A. So how to close this Activity B? can i directly use clientSocket.close() in Activity B?

Comment: @vij: No. You move the socket logic into a service, as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: can you provide some example/reference?

Comment: @vij: You can learn about services [on the Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).