# How to use Socket as Intent extra in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, android-intent

I want to start a service which needs to send and receive somthing through an open `Socket` connection. That `Socket` is a field of an object, like this:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    Socket socket;
}
```

I was planning to pass this object as an Intent extra:

```
A a = getInstanceOfA(); // Get an instance of A from somewhere.
intent.putExtra("A", a);
```

Of course, `A` is serializable, because it needs to be, in order to put it as an intent extra. But wait. Socket is not serializable.

How can I fix it?

- Can I mark the socket as `transient`, so it doesn't get serialized? Or would I, when doing so, no longer be able to send some bytes through that socket?
- Or should I quit using `Service`s and `BroadcastReceiver`s and use another approach?
- Or is there another way to accomplish the abovementioned goal?

PS: I already [read something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070966/how-to-send-tcp-sockets-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android) about transferring `InputStream`s and `Socket`s between `Activity`s, but the given answer is not very clear.

Comment: I'm not aware that you can do that with an Intent.  If you know the sender and receiver are in the same process you can use a singleton or other global solution.  Otherwise, there are behind-the-scenes tricks built in to both Android and the underlying Linux which support passing of working sockets between processes, respectively in Binder (ie, AIDL service connections) or in Unix Domain sockets (LocalSockets in Java speak).

Comment: Basically the link you included is suggesting that wanting to do this is a symptom of a bad design and that you would do better to put all the socket interaction in a Service; in many cases I'd agree, though it is possible by the alternate methods I listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without some possibly dirty hacks.

As [Chris Stratton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton) – credits to him – mentioned, one could bypass the problem by retrieving it by a static object or singleton.

Alternatively, one could alter the application structure, so the service itself creates the Socket or controls it.